# Pass list of strings into a module and then create array Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs

I am currently creating a Terraform module that creates some ECS tasks. I want to be able to pass a list of commands so I can specify the command field for a certain task.

I currently pass my list into my module like so:

```
module "test" {
  source = "git@github.com:test/deploy.git"
  task_count = 3

  entryPoints = [
    "run, -c, /app/node/node_0, --bootnode, true",
    "run, -c, /app/node/node_1",
    "run, -c, /app/node/node_2",
  ]
}
```

And then I want to pass each command into it's task here:

```
data "template_file" "test" {
  template = file("${path.module}/templates/test.json.tpl")
  count = var.task_count

  vars = {
    entryPoint = split(",", element(var.entryPoints, count.index)),
  }
}
```

I was hoping `element(var.entryPoints, count.index)` meant for the first task it would pass in

`"run", "-c", "/app/node/node_0", "--bootnode", "true"`

Then for the second task

`"run", "-c", "/app/node/node_1"`

etc

However, I'm receiving the error:

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on .terraform/modules/test/ecs_task_definition.tf line 5, in data "template_file" "test":
   5:   vars = {
  12:   entryPoint = split(",", element(var.entryPoints, count.index)),
  15:   }

Inappropriate value for attribute "vars": element "entryPoint": string
required.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`maint.tf`

```
variable "entrypoints_list" {
  default = [
    "run, -c, /app/node/node_0, --bootnode, true",
    "run, -c, /app/node/node_1",
    "run, -c, /app/node/node_2",
  ]
}
locals {
  entryPoints = [for key in var.entrypoints_list : split(",", key)]
}

data "template_file" "container_definition" {
  count = length(local.entryPoints)
  template = file("${path.module}/templates/container-definition.json.tpl")
  vars = {
    entryPoint             =  jsonencode(element(local.entryPoints,count.index))
  }
}

output "container-definition" {
  value = data.template_file.container_definition[*].rendered
}
```

`container-definition.json.tpl`

```
  
{
  "entryPoint": ${entryPoint}
}
```

`terraform plan`

```sh
  + container-definition = [
      + jsonencode(
            {
              + entryPoint = [
                  + "run",
                  + " -c",
                  + " /app/node/node_0",
                  + " --bootnode",
                  + " true",
                ]
            }
        ),
      + jsonencode(
            {
              + entryPoint = [
                  + "run",
                  + " -c",
                  + " /app/node/node_1",
                ]
            }
        ),
      + jsonencode(
            {
              + entryPoint = [
                  + "run",
                  + " -c",
                  + " /app/node/node_2",
                ]
            }
        ),
    ]
```

As per your requirement, you can move the code around in a module.